# files responce from one server to other domains

Tags: php

Greeting all,

this is my first post here,,

Actually i have a complete website like(www.example.com) with admin interface, and i want to share same website to different domains like(www.example2.com, www.example3.com, www.example4.com),

with this example2.com, example3.com, example4.com can change his contents from example.com to using the admin interface,,

i m beginner so i don't have any idea ,,

i m waiting for response pls let me know if you understand my question??

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: If you want to display the exact same website on different domain, just add a server alias to your apache configuration (assuming you use Apache).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ServerAlias directive on your apache configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example2.com example3.com example4.com example5.com 
# ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks sathia for your response, but actually i am describe in details i have my own server and and i have a script(www.example.com) of a website in php, the main thing is that i want to provide a service through that script, i have two clients(example2.com, and example3.com), but i don't want to share or give that script to my clients, just want to provide a service ,,  let me know if you understand well

Comment: no, it's not clear what you want to do. if you add some ServerAlias you won't give to your clients any script, they will just access the same host but with a different host name. try to explain better what you want to achieve

Comment: i don't know how to explain you but it's ok, i will try. Thanks a lot to give your time friend, do you have any email id so that i will contact you i future if you don't mind?